# Python module runs fine, encoding error when importing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, pyscripter

I am a trying to advance my very basic python skills by putting often used scripts in modules and then importing them when I need them. However, I directly face trouble.

The script runs fine on its own but when I try to import any script I have made myself I get an encoding error. I have tried searching for an answer but in the jungle of encoding-related questions I can't find anything useful.

For the sake of simplifying my problem I now have the following code:
In importtest.py

```
# coding= UTF-8
def importedmodule():
    print "imported stuff happened"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    importedmodule()
```

In startingfile.py:

```
# coding= utf-8
import importtest
```

importtest.py runs fine on its own but when I try to run startingfile.py (I use PyScripter 2.5.3 and Python 2.7.10) I get the following Error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '/xff' in file
>   \server\users$\username\My Folder\importtest.py on line 1, but no
>   encoding declare; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
>   (importtest.py, line 1)

The server, username and folder names are omitted but contain (as far as I see) no special characters.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without having the code of importtest.py

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I solved the issue (without learning anything).
By making a copy of an existing module and pasting my own code into that module (and changing file name) it runs fine. So I guess there is some hidden overhead information that made trouble.

So, same code different file. Works.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7 the following header works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Could it be some kind of system variable? Or caused by the editor?

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and have no Error.
So that is not coding error.
Maybe error by your path have symbol character.

Comment: I suppose so. I now tried putting the files in directly in c:\ and it still gives the same error. Could it be some kind of system setting?